# Unbinding drawables from view on onDestroy()

Tags: android, android-activity, memory-leaks, bitmap, android-imageview

I read a lot about memory leaks in the last few days, and came across some interesting stuff.
I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6779164/2463875) to a basic Android bitmap-related memory leak question (the answer is from 2011) and I was wondering if this is still the case.
If I'm using views that contain bitmaps in my activity (ImageViews, TextViews...), do I really need to unbind their drawables when destroying the activity?
Is this only in some cases or always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no longer necessary as of 4.0, as the callback is now stored in a `WeakReference`.

[From 2.3.7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java#Drawable.setCallback%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.Callback%29):

```
public final void setCallback(Callback cb) {
    mCallback = cb;
}
```

and [in 4.0.1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java#Drawable.setCallback%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.Callback%29):

```
public final void setCallback(Callback cb) {
    mCallback = new WeakReference<Callback>(cb);
}
```